# Read integer from XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I got this xml file from where i want to get the amount of money from

```
<data>
  <money>300</money>
  <lives>10</lives>
  <start>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>-1</y>
    <direction>down</direction>
  </start>
  <waves>
    <wave>
      <slimes>5</slimes>
      <healthPerSlime>60</healthPerSlime>
      <money>25</money>
    </wave>
    <wave>
      <slimes>10</slimes>
      <healthPerSlime>80</healthPerSlime>
      <money>30</money>
    </wave>
  </waves>
</data>
```

i tried it in 2 ways:

```
money = int.Parse(xmlDoc.Elements().Select(x => x.Element("money").Value).ToString());
```

and:

```
money = int.Parse((from element in xmlDoc.Descendants("money")
                              select element.Value).ToString());
```

but i keep getting a FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format."

can someone tell me what im doing wrong.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You have `money` at root level which is `300` and then you have `money` with `wave`, which one you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
xmlDoc.Elements()
      .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Element("money").Value))
      .Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast `money` element to integer. XElements supports explicit casting to string, boolean, integer and some other types. E.g. if you want value of data element money:

```
money = (int)xmlDoc.Root.Element("money"); // 300
```

Parsing of wave's money will look like:

```
var data = xmlDoc.Root;
int money = (int)data.Element("money"); // 300
int lives = (int)data.Element("lives"); // 10
var waves = from w in data.Element("waves").Elements()
            select new {
               Slimes = (int)w.Element("slimes"),
               HealthPerSlime = (int)w.Element("healthPerSlime"),
               Money = (int)w.Element("money")
            };
```

That will return collection of two anonymous 'wave' objects (consider to create class for this data) with `slimes`, `healthPerSlime` and `money` parsed as integers.

Answer (score 0):

everyone seems to be giving you an answer using functions so I'll give one using the linq syntax

```
int money = 
    from element in xmlDoc.Root
    where element.Name == "money"
    select int.Parse(element.Value)).First();
```

so lets break it down.

`xmlDoc.Root` brings you to `<data>` then you search all of the elements at the next level and return all of them `where .Name == "money"` and then you select the `.Value` of those and parse them into an int.  This returns a list of items so you just grab the `.First()` one and return it to `money`.